# Goland --- "Go to implementation" just opens up the file but doesn't scroll up to the definition

Tags: macos, go, goland

Using "Go to implementation" or "Cmd + Left Click" on a function usage opens up the file, but doesn't automatically scroll to the function definition. It used to work fine, but suddenly started breaking one day.

OS: MacOS
IDE: Goland

Answer (score 2):

Well a plugin was causing this issue --- https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16429-idea-resolve-symlinks. Disabling it fixed the code navigation.